# handle onchange triggered by third party javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a third party javascript that changes the value of a textbox when a button is clicked with the following script:

```
$("#button").click(function (e) {
    //Code in this function is from a third party source and i can't modify it!
    var elt = $("#text").get(0);
    elt.value = "test";
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        elt.fireEvent("onchange");
    } else if (document.createEvent) {
        var e = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        e.initEvent("change", true, true);
        elt.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
});
```

But this does not seem to trigger `$.change` so how would i detect this event?

Restrictions: I can't modify the third party javascript and i can't modify the html for the textbox.

the following doesn't work:

```
$("#text").change(function () {
    alert("Change!");
});
```

Full test source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#text").change(function () {
                    alert("Change!");
                });
                $("#button").click(function (e) {
                    //Code in this function is from a third party source and i can't modify it!
                    var elt = $("#text").get(0);
                    elt.value = "test";
                    if (document.createEventObject) {
                        elt.fireEvent("onchange");
                    } else if (document.createEvent) {
                        var e = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                        e.initEvent("change", true, true);
                        elt.dispatchEvent(e);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="text" type="text" onchange="javascript:alert('onchange')" />
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Test" />
    </body>
</html>
```

The target browser is IE11, but the solution should work in all browsers!

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem is what you are having is a jquery less event handler not triggering the jquery event stream.

This probably has to do with the order of binding events. If the "vanilla" event handler is bound before jQuery it will get fired first. And if it has a redirect as you implied the browser will promptly call onunload and execute cleanup never executing your script.

It would help if I knew what you would want to be the result of catching this event.

if you want to stop the unload you can simply unbind the the event listener that redirects your page

document.getElementById('test').removeEventListener('change');

If you want jQuery bound before the script the third party has got its hooks in you need to unbind the event, add the jQuery event listener then reattach the 3rd party event.

There is no other way to intercept it in time before unload because the script will always beat jQuery to the punch in adding the event handler unless you can manipulate the script loading order in such a way your event handler will get bound first before the event handler of the 3rd party script.

It would help to see the full example with 3rd party script.

Comment: First of this should be a comment as its not solution and as i said `Restrictions: I can't modify the third party javascript and i can't modify the html for the textbox.`

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for modifying your answer but this behavior happens in my example and there is not redirect there?

Comment: Well, you want to capture the event? is it in an iframe or loaded in your page directly? If it's loaded in an iframe and its not from same domain as your website you can't do a thing.  If you load it dynamically you can try to unbind all event handlers with $('#text').unbind(). I really need to know more about circumstances to be able to help you

Comment: sorry i don't understand why you need more when you have a example where the incorrect behavior exists. Why add more logic that has nothing to do with the error? (but no its not in a iframe, copy the source i have in my question save it to a html file and open in IE11...)

Comment: Because with me it just triggers the alert after I clicked or changed it just as logic predicts as it should? maybe my computer is special heh. With me the event flow just works as it should. That's why i'd like to study it in the "wild"

Comment: it should trigger 2 alerts, one from `onchange` and one from `$("#text").change(`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit strange that .change() not fires up, maybe as a workaround it is possible to set the timer?

```
var lastValue = '';
setInterval(function() {
    if ($("#text").val() != lastValue) {
       lastValue = $("#text").val();
        console.log('I am definitely sure the text box realy realy changed     this time');
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Neat solution but the problem is that a redirect is made after the value is changed (this you could not know as i didn't include it in my question).